# Uploading and creating a table using Dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am new to Plotly Dash and i want to upload a csv file and create a table. I am able to upload the csv file but it is uploaded as tuple not as a pandas DataFrame so i can't view it using TableData.

```
app.layout =html.Div([
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload',
            children=html.Button('Import un fichier'),
              ),
        html.Div(id="output_data"),])



def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(",")
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if "csv" in filename: #csv file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")), delimiter=',', decimal=','),
            print(type(df)),
        elif "xls" in filename: #xls file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div(["There was an error processing this file."])
    print(df)

    return df



 @app.callback(
     Output("output_data", "children"),
     Input("upload", "contents"),
     Input("upload", "filename"),
)
def update_table(contents, filename):
    # table = html.Div()
    if contents:
        df=parse_data(contents,filename)
        table = html.Div(
            [
                html.H4(filename),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                    data=df.to_dict("records"),

                ),
                html.Hr(),
                html.Div("Raw Content"),
                html.Pre(
                    contents[0:200] + "...",
                    style={"whiteSpace": "pre-wrap", "wordBreak": "break-all"},
                ),
            ]
        )

        return table
```

I am having this error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'columns'`

Comment: `return html.Div(["There was an error processing this file."])` remove this and raise an exception in that place. Currently if any error, df will hold this instead of a dataframe.

Comment: But like i said i am able to upload the csv file and print it in the console but i dont know why it is uploaded as a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```py
if "csv" in filename: #csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")), delimiter=',', decimal=','),
    print(type(df)),
```

You've added commas to the end of these lines! That makes the values tuples. Just remove those commas, like this:

```py
if "csv" in filename: #csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")), delimiter=',', decimal=',')
    print(type(df))
```